# Split command output in batch

Tags: batch-file

I have this command that gives lists of directories and their filepath:

```
for /d %%D in (C:\OS\system\DisplayLanguages) do echo %%~fD
```

I need to separate the last part of the output eg. "C:\OS\system\DisplayLanguages\en", so I would have just the folder names.

Comment: The best tool for this is one of the Windows ports of the Unix `sed` utility (search for `sed.exe`, or obtain MS's _Services For Unix_): just pipe the output through `sed` with an appropriate editing command and each line will be edited as it's generated. It helps to be familiar with regular expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Windows batch, the `%%~fD` returns [Fully qualified path name](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html), so you could use

```
for /d %%D in (C:\OS\system\DisplayLanguages\*) do @echo %%~nxD
```

E.g. in my Windows from command line:

```
FOR /D %G in (%windir%\system32\*) DO @Echo %~nxG
```

The same as

```
FOR /F "tokens=*" %G in ('dir /B /AD %windir%\system32\*') DO @Echo %~nxG
```

Answer (score 0):

I just figured out that you can get the wanted output by simple command:

```
dir /a:d /b
```